If foreach was allowed on a null Collection (& just skipped the loop without an NPE), would that be any different than a null check on the Collection?
Let's imagine that a java for-each was allowed on a null java.util.Collection whose behavior would be to skip the iteration loop without throwing a NullPointerException, would that be functionally different than wrapping a null check around the loop?
E.g If this were allowed:
        var x = (Collection<String>) null;
        for (String y : x) {
            something();
        }

would it be functionally different than:
        var x = (Collection<String>) null;
        if (x != null) {
            for (String y : x) {
                something();
            }
        }

Perhaps this isn't allowed because it requires the check to happen implicitly in byte code, adding an additional instruction?  Or does that check have to happen anyway to be able to throw the NPE?

You're the one posing an alternative universe. You're the only one who can answer that question.

If that were possible, then the JDK developers would have to decide whether or not that would be equivalent.  (Fortunately, they haven't.  Throwing a NullPointerException is right and proper.)

the nest step would be similar behavior regarding method calls, that is, calling a method on null would just do nothing ... and more errors go unnoticed or harder to find :-/

A null value is an error.  It is never correct to treat null as equivalent to an empty Collection or array. If code wants to represent an empty Collection or array, it should pass an empty Collection or array.  They’re easy to create.

The null check is happening indeed, but it happening on low level of byte code execution. At that point there are no for loops just jumps.
If you want to introduce such behavior you need to make compiler emit additional bytecode to check for null and skip to the end of the loop. It is only couple of bytecode instructions, but they will be everywhere. Granted they may be eliminated by JIT, since check is done anyway.
Other option is to introduce specialized bytecode instruction that will do the trick and allow JIT to skip unnecessary checks.
So answering your question: It is theoretically possible. Why it wasn't implemented we can only guess.
One argument against it is it will complicate already complicated semantics of extended for loop.

As far as I am aware, there are no implicit null checks even at the bytecode level.  The NPE you get when you try to dereference a null reference comes all the way from the internals of the bytecode interpreter / JIT-ed machine code.

@JohnBollinger Yes. I was talking about that check.

Thanks.  I see now that for-each is a invokeinterface on Iterator.hasNext() etc.  None of that is being checked.
